# Options for .hidden files?

Tags: linux, directory, nautilus

What options exist for the `.hidden` file? I wanted to hide certain filetypes in a folder, but simply putting `*.out`, which I assumed would hide all files ending in `.out`, didn't work. :(

I'm using Nautilus.

UPDATE: I guess if this option doesn't exist, a bash shell could be created that, when executed in a directory, finds all files with matching endings and writes them to the `.hidden` file. I don't have any experience with the command-line but I'll try this :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer:
It seems you meant something other than I thought you did. You create a literal `.hidden` file listing all the files you want the Nautilus file manager to hide by default you can use this command (from @Jóhann 's answer):

```
for i in *.out; do echo "$i"; done > .hidden
```

Replacing `.out` with the file extension you wish to hide.

Old answer:

If all the files in question share the same extension, and no other files do, then a simple shell command will do the trick. For example, for `*.out` files:

```
for i in ./*.out; do mv "$i" ./."${i#./}"; done
```

This command will move all files in the current directory matching *.out to `.<name>.out`

Comment: `basename` is almost never necessary because simple parameter expansion can do its job.  Also, for maximum safety, prefix globs with `./`.  `for i in ./*.out; do mv "$i" ./"${i#./}"; done`

Comment: @jw013 I get a syntax error with your version.

Comment: Fixed: `for i in ./*.out; do mv "$i" ./."${i#./}"; done`  I forgot the `.` in the destination so it would have tried to rename a file to itself.  There should be no syntax error, just a logic error in the original.

Comment: That fixed it; added to answer.

Comment: Oooo, this is cool. But can this be modified to add filenames matching a chosen file ending to a `.hidden` file. The scenario where that would be beneficial is in a directory containing only a `.tex` and its associated files that I don't need to see. I assume the compiler couldn't find the files with the dot in front, so a more practical solution seems to be to keep the filenames (which will be constant) in a .hidden file

Comment: I think I understand now. You mean the literal file named `.hidden` which the Nautilus file manager parses to hide files **other ** than those with the standard `.name` convention. I have amended my answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I'll improve Jóhann's answer a bit. Instead of overwriting the whole file, this command checks whether a file name is already in the `.hidden` file, and appends it if not.

```
for i in *.out; do grep -qxF "$i" tout || echo $i; done
```

If you want a more general script, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ $# -gt 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 [directory [extension [listfile]]]"
        echo 'Defaults to "." ".out" ".hidden"'
        exit 1
fi

# Apply defaults.
dir=${1:-.}
ext=${2:-.out}
listf=${3:-.hidden}

# Construct the list file.
list="$dir/$listf"

# Make sure the list file exists or the first `grep` will print an error.
[ -f "$list" ] || touch "$list"

# Glob all the files
for filename in "$dir"/*"$ext"; do
        # Check whether the list contains the file name
        if ! grep -qxF "$filename" "$list"; then
                # If not, add it.
                echo "$filename" >>"$list"
        fi
done
```

Comment: Nice, I'll have to dig through this and try and understand the code. This could easily be modified to take a list of extensions, yes?

Comment: @Jóhann Yes, it shouldn't be too hard to modify it. It'll be a good exercise for you, but if you have trouble getting it right, comment again and I'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Amazed, I created a shell command to do what I needed it to do.

```
for i in *.out; do echo "$i"; done > .hidden
```

This seems to work, is it possible to apply a shell command to all subdirectories of a chosen directory (actually, that's probably another question)